# Using a geometry polygon to fence other polygons

Tags: javascript, google-maps

A little background.  This map draws polygons on the quarter of each minute. They are labelled as such.  That seems to work fine.  I am adding a second polygon that is editable and draggable to the map which the user is permitted to select quarter minutes by expanding the handles on the gridSelectBox and then click outside of the selected area. I will be written the quarter minute to a database.

That works but with issues.

Sometimes only every other column or row (Long or Lat) is selected though it is clearly in the selected area.  I can only assume it is some sort of rounding area.  I did notice that what should be a perfect degree X degree vertices 34.00 X -84.00 appears as 34.00000000000001 X -84.00.  Could that be the problem, and if so, how do I correct for it?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/99rr7a8k/)

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type ="text/javascript"
             src ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&amp;libraries=geometry&amp;sensor=false"></script>
    <title>Find your Qtr minute locator</title>
</head>
<body style="height:100%;margin:0">
<!-- Declare the div, make it take up the full document body -->
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%; height: 100%;"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

        var map;

        var qtrArray = [];
        var Startlatlng = "";
        var llOffset =((1/60)/4);

        var drawGridSelectBox = false;
        var firstRun = true;
        var drawGridBox = false;
        var gridOverBox = new google.maps.Polygon();
        var gridSelectBox = new google.maps.Polygon();

        var gridline;
        var polylinesquare;
        var latPolylines = [];

        var latLabels = [];
        var latMapLabel;

        var lngPolylines = [];

        var lngLabels = [];
        var lngMapLabel;
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

        function initialize() {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(34.0, -84.0),
                zoom: 16,
                streetViewControl: true,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                scaleControl: true
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function (event) {
                if (!google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, gridSelectBox)) {
                    map.setZoom(16);
                    createGridSelectBox(event.latLng);
                    ClearGrid();
                    for(var x=0;x<latPolylines.length;++x){
                        for(var y=0;y<lngPolylines.length-1;++y){
                            var latLng=new google.maps.LatLng(latPolylines[x].getPath().getAt(0).lat(),
                                    lngPolylines[y].getPath().getAt(0).lng());

                            if ((google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(latLng, gridSelectBox))&&(!firstRun))
                            {
                                drawGridBox = true;
                                createGridBox(latLng);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    firstRun = false;
                    map.panTo(event.latLng);
                    drawGridBox = false;

                }});
            DrawGridOn();
            google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function () {
                createGridLines(map.getBounds());
            });
        }
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);

        function DrawGridOn() {
            drawGridSelectBox = true;
        }

        function DrawGridOff() {
            drawGridSelectBox = false;
        }



        function createGridLines(bounds) {
            for (var i = 0; i < latPolylines.length; i++) {
                latPolylines[i].setMap(null);
            }

            latPolylines = [];
            for (var j = 0; j < lngPolylines.length; j++) {
                lngPolylines[j].setMap(null);
            }
            lngPolylines = [];

            if (map.getZoom() < 14) return;
            var north = bounds.getNorthEast().lat();
            var east  = bounds.getNorthEast().lng();
            var south = bounds.getSouthWest().lat();
            var west  = bounds.getSouthWest().lng();

             // define the size of the grid
            var topLat    = Math.ceil(north / llOffset) * llOffset;
            var rightLong = Math.ceil(east / llOffset) * llOffset;

            var bottomLat = Math.floor(south / llOffset) * llOffset;
            var leftLong  = Math.floor(west / llOffset) * llOffset;

            for (var latitude = bottomLat; latitude <= topLat; latitude += llOffset) latPolylines.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                    new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, leftLong), new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, rightLong)],
                map: map,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeWeight: 1
            }));
            for (var longitude = leftLong; longitude <= rightLong; longitude += llOffset) lngPolylines.push(new google.maps.Polyline({
                path: [
                    new google.maps.LatLng(topLat, longitude), new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLat, longitude)],
                map: map,
                geodesic: true,
                strokeColor: "#0000FF",
                strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                strokeWeight: 1
            }));

            if (map.getZoom() < 15) {
              for (var i = 0; i < lngLabels.length; i++) {
                   lngLabels[i].setMap(null);
              }
                 lngLabels = [];
              return;
            }  // set lngLabels to null

            for(var x=0;x<latPolylines.length;++x){
                for(var y=0;y<lngPolylines.length-1;++y){
                    var latLng=new google.maps.LatLng(latPolylines[x].getPath().getAt(0).lat(),
                            lngPolylines[y].getPath().getAt(0).lng());

                    var qtrLatLng = ddToQM(latLng.lat(), latLng.lng());

                    lngLabels.push(new google.maps.Marker({
                        map:map,
                        position:latLng,
                        icon:{  url:"https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?"
                        +"chst=d_bubble_text_small&chld=bb|"
                        + latLng
                        +"|FFFFFF|000000",
                            anchor:new google.maps.Point(0,42)
                       }
                  }));
                }
            }
        }  // end createGridLines

        function createGridSelectBox(point) {
             // Square limits
            var smPoint = point;
            var babyOffset = (llOffset/2);
            var bottomLeftLat = (Math.floor(point.lat() / llOffset) * llOffset)-babyOffset;
            var bottomLeftLong = (Math.floor(point.lng() / llOffset) * llOffset) - babyOffset;


            var gridLineSquare = [
                new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong),  //lwr left
                new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong + llOffset),  //lwr right
                new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat + llOffset, bottomLeftLong + llOffset),  //upr right
                new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat + llOffset, bottomLeftLong),  //upr left
                new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong)];  //lwr left

            if (drawGridSelectBox == true) {
                gridSelectBox = new google.maps.Polygon({
                    path: gridLineSquare,
                    draggable:true,
                    geodesic:true,
                    editable :true,
                    fillColor: "#FF0000",
                    fillOpacity: 0.35,
                    strokeColor: "#CC0099",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                    strokeWeight: 2
                });

                gridSelectBox.setMap(map);
                drawGridSelectBox = false;
            }
        }

        function ClearGrid() {
            if (qtrArray) {
                for (i in qtrArray) {
                    qtrArray[i].setMap(null);
                }
            }
            qtrArray=[];
        }


        function createGridBox(point) {
            // Square limits

            var smPoint = point;

            var bottomLeftLat = Math.floor(point.lat() / llOffset) * llOffset;
            var bottomLeftLong = Math.floor(point.lng() / llOffset) * llOffset;


            var gridLineSquare = [
                new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong),  //lwr left
                new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong + llOffset),  //lwr right
                new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat + llOffset, bottomLeftLong + llOffset),  //upr right
                new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat + llOffset, bottomLeftLong),  //upr left
                new google.maps.LatLng(bottomLeftLat, bottomLeftLong)];  //lwr left

            if (drawGridBox == true) {

                gridOverBox = new google.maps.Polygon({
                    path: gridLineSquare,
                    draggable:false,
                    geodesic:true,
                    editable :false,
                    fillColor: "#EAED00",
                    fillOpacity: 0.35,
                    strokeColor: "#CC0099",
                    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                    strokeWeight: 2
                });


                gridOverBox.setMap(map);
                qtrArray.push(gridOverBox);

            }
        }

        function ddToQM(alat, alng) {
            var latResult, lngResult, dmsResult;

            alat = parseFloat(alat);
            alng = parseFloat(alng);

            latResult = (alat >= 0)? "" : "";
            latResult += getDms(alat);
            lngResult = (alng >= 0)? "" : "";
            lngResult += getDms(alng);
            dmsResult = latResult + lngResult;

            // Return the resultant string.
            return dmsResult;
        }


        function getDms(val) {

            // Required variables
            var valDeg, valMin, valSec, interimResult;
            var qtrMin;

            val = Math.abs(val);

            // ---- Degrees ----

            valDeg = Math.floor(val);
            valMin = Math.floor((val - valDeg) * 60);
            valSec = Math.round((val - valDeg - valMin / 60) * 3600 * 1000) / 1000;

            if (valSec == 60){
                valMin +=1;
                valSec = 0;
            }
            if (valMin == 60){
                valMin +=1;
                valSec = 0;
            }
            interimResult = valDeg+"";

            if (valMin<10){
                valMin = "0"+valMin;
            }
            interimResult += valMin + "";

            switch(valSec){
                case  0 : qtrMin = "A";
                    break;
                case 15 : qtrMin = "B";
                    break;
                case 30 : qtrMin = "C";
                    break;
                case 45 : qtrMin = "D";
                    break;

            }
            interimResult += qtrMin;
            return interimResult;
        }

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

After weeks of ripping my script apart, I finally found it.  The issue was the LLOffset constant.  The grid boxes are to be 1/4th minute X 1/4th minute.  Thus the constant of
 var llOffset = (1/60)/4);
or 1 degree/60 minutes / 4

I used the fractional computation and let JavaScript decide the format.
JS determined that  1/60)/4 = 0.004166666666666667 or 18 significant digits yet when it computes a LatLng, it uses only 14 significant digits.  Normally the difference would not matter but every so often, that .000000000000006667 was enough to push my polygon anchor into the next grid.

Simply changing llOffset to 0.00416666666667 (the same as google maps LatLng, corrected the problem.

This may be useful information when close tolerance is desired.